# Debug and triggered pipeline executing twice

Tags: azure-data-factory

I've created a simple pipeline with a number of copy activities. When I attempt to debug or "trigger now" the pipeline starts executing and then after about a minute, a message flashes, and another instance of the pipeline starts.

Message Screenshot:

[image: Message Screenshot]

Anybody experience this or know how to prevent it?

Comment: Hi @Michael, welcome to Stack Overflow!  If my answer is helpful for you, please accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. If you have any other concerns, please feel free to reply me, Thank you.

Comment: Hi @Michael: If my response helped you, can you please mark it as an answer so that we can have others from community to benefit from it. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Please check the trigger definition, below is a sample trigger.

In this you can set the trigger schedules.

In your case, I think the Recurrence is Every 1 Min(s).

You can change it according to your use case.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Hello Pratik, this is a brand new pipleine that does not have any assigned triggers.

Comment: okay, so have you checked the Triggers section and find it empty?

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you just do a debug ? I think you have two triggers whcih are associated and so when you do "trigger now" both of them are getting fired . May be the below screenshot help to check that .
[image]

Comment: Hello, the same issue occurs when I run debug. Two pipelines execute back to back.Please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/229287/data-factory-pipeline-executes-twice.html for more info including run-ids

Answer (score 0):

As a supplement, you could go to **Monitor-->Pipeline run-->Trigger/Degbug** to check the pipeline run history.
[image]

Then you could know how the pipeline runs, manual debug(triggered) running or trigger triggered.
[image]

Then remove the trigger related like @HimanshuSinha-msft said.

Also please make sure you are the only one who operate the pipeline in the current time and the pipeline is not triggered or called by other services or executed by other pipeline actives, , such as logic app,  etc..

HTH.

Comment: Hello Leon, there is no trigger assigned to this pipeline, all instances are set to manual trigger

Comment: @Michael Got it. Did the pipeline really run two times or not the message delay? Refresh the Data Factory, If the issue never happen again, then we could just ignore it. I consider that it's just an accident.

Comment: The pipeline really did run 2 times, I had double the data inserted. The issue happened multiple times and is repeatable. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/229287/data-factory-pipeline-executes-twice.html for more info including run IDs. I did discover that, the issue does not occur if the pipeline is assigned a trigger and executed via a schedule.

Comment: Thanks for the details @Michael, we're not the Microsoft engineer so that we can not check the details in the backend. Which browser did you use? It seams that the debug  command must be sent twice.